# Using regex to retrieve the Prometheus metric name from Grafana expressions

Tags: java, regex, grafana, prometheus, regex-group

I've tried many different `regex` patterns to get it but not quite successfully.

The patterns to this question:

```
<method_name(> metric_name <{filter_condition}> <[time_duration]> <)> <by (some members)>
            ^------------------------------------------------------^
                          method_name(...) can be multiple
```

As you can see, the `<...>` can be optional while the `metric_name` will be a must which I wanna retrieve from this `equation`.

```
Case # 1
input: sum(log_search_by_service_total {service_name!~\"\"}) by (service_name, operator)
output: log_search_by_service_total

Case # 2
input: log_request_total
output: log_request_total

Case # 3
input:  sum(delta(log_request_total[5m])) by (args, user_id)
output: log_request_total

Case # 4
input: log_request_total{methodName=~\"getAppDynamicsGraphMetrics|getAppDynamicsMetrics\"}
output: log_request_total

Case # 5
input: sum(delta(log_request_total{className=~\".*ProductDashboardController\",methodName=~\"getDashboardConfig|updateMaintainers|addQuickLink|deleteQuickLink|addDependentMiddleware|addDependentService|updateErrorThreshold\"}[5m])) by (user_id)"
output: log_request_total

Case # 6
input: count_scalar(sum(log_query_request_total) by (user_id))
output: log_query_request_total
```

Here is a demo for what I've tried in Java. But it seems I cannot get the right `pattern` to retrieve the exact answer for the patterns I mentioned above.

Please share some ideas if it's possible.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] exprs = {"sum(log_query_task_cache_hit_rate_bucket)by(le)",
            "sum(log_search_by_service_total {service_name!~\"\"}) by (service_name, operator)",
            "log_request_total",
            " sum(delta(log_request_total[5m])) by (args, user_id)",
            "log_request_total{methodName=~\"getAppDynamicsGraphMetrics|getAppDynamicsMetrics\"}",
            "sum(delta(log_request_total{className=~\".*ProductDashboardController\",methodName=~\"getDashboardConfig|updateMaintainers|addQuickLink|deleteQuickLink|addDependentMiddleware|addDependentService|updateErrorThreshold\"}[5m])) by (user_id)",
            "sum(log_request_total{methodName=\"getInstanceNames\"}) by (user_id)",
            "sum(log_request_total{methodName=\"getVpcCardInfo\",user_id!~\"${user}\"}) by (envName)",
            "count_scalar(sum(log_query_request_total) by (user_id))",
            "avg(log_waiting_time_average) by (exported_tenant, exported_landscape)",
            "avg(task_processing_time_average{app=\"athena\"})",
            "avg(log_queue_time_average) by (log_type)",
            "sum(delta(product_dashboard_service_sum[2m]))",
            "ceil(delta(product_dashboard_service_count[5m]))]"
    };
    String[] expected = {
            "log_query_task_cache_hit_rate_bucket",
            "log_search_by_service_total",
            "log_request_total",
            "log_request_total",
            "log_request_total",
            "log_request_total",
            "log_request_total",
            "log_request_total",
            "log_query_request_total",
            "log_waiting_time_average",
            "task_processing_time_average",
            "log_queue_time_average",
            "product_dashboard_service_sum",
            "product_dashboard_service_count"
    };
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\(?([\\w|_]+)\\{?\\[?.*");
    testPattern(exprs, expected, pattern);
    pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\(?([\\w|_]+)\\{?\\[?.*");
    testPattern(exprs, expected, pattern);
    pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\(?([\\w|_]+)\\{?\\[?.*");
    testPattern(exprs, expected, pattern);
}

private static void testPattern(String[] exprs, String[] expected, Pattern pattern) {
    System.out.println("\n********** Pattern Match Test *********\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < exprs.length; ++i) {
        String expr = exprs[i];
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expr);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("\nThe Original Expr: " + expr);
            System.out.println(String.format("Expected:\t %-40s Matched:\t %-40s", expected[i], matcher.group(1)));
        } else {
            System.out.println("expected: " + expected[i] + " not matched");
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### UPDATE 2018-08-06

Thanks for the help of Bohemian, it really enlightened me (since I always believe `regex` can do magic with clean solution).

Later on, I found out that the `expr`s are more complex than I anticipated, as things as follows come up:

```
Case # 7
input: topk(10,autoindex_online_consume_time_total_sum{app=~"$app", DTO_Name=~"$c_class"})
expected: autoindex_online_consume_time_total_sum
// to get the metric name: autoindex_online_consume_time_total_sum
// still I can make it work with small modifications as ^(?:\w+\()*(?:\d+,)*(\w+)
```

But the following one and even more different complicated combinations as it made me turn to the reliable method:

```
Case # 8
input: sum(hue_mail_sent_attachment_bytes_total) by (app)  / sum(hue_mail_sent_mails_with_attachment_total) by (app)
Expected: [hue_mail_sent_attachment_bytes_total, hue_mail_sent_mails_with_attachment_total]
```

Much more complicated now...and even **unpredictable** since there is no way to control the `expr` input from the users.

So I achieve the same goal with more reliable and plain solutions:

1. storing the `distinct` metric names first into the db;
2. as the `expr` comes, check it in memory using `contains(String s)`;
3. still there might be an issue: over-matching if some metric names contains others;

Comment: This looks far too complicated for RegEx. For something this complex you probably want a lexer and an AST generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex captures your target in group 1

```
^(?:\w+\()*(\w+)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/SA3EovEjY4).

In java, to get your target:

```
String metricName = input.replaceAll("^(?:\\w+\\()*(\\w+)", "$1");
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, @Bohemian. So terse and clean it is. `^(?:\w+\()*` will match all the `method_name(` repetitions and just after the repetition (zero or more) there it is => the `METRIC_NAME` I am searching for. Great solution ;)

Comment: Still I need to make small modifications for extra white spaces to ensure it will always work. Thanks for the help ~ @Bohemian. ^(?:\\s*\\w+\\s*\\(\\s*)*\\s*(\w+)